# tensorflow . Tensor("Mul:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following python file, when i ran it, it shows errors, how can i solve it pls?

```
-----------------------
import tensorflow as tf

x1 = tf.constant(5)
x2 = tf.constant(6)

result = tf.multiply(x1,x2)

print(result)
--------------------
error:
Tensor("Mul:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Care to share the errors? Is that all you get?

Comment: yes, that is all i got, the output.

Comment: you may need to use `tf.scalar_mul(x1, x2)` instead

Answer (score 1):

What you have done up to now is create a (very simple) computational graph. In order to actually do any computations, you need a *session* and use the *run* method.

I strongly suggest you to to read https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started to understand tensorflow's computational model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x1 = tf.constant(5)
x2 = tf.constant(6)
result = tf.multiply(x1,x2)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(result)
```

[EDIT] I should also add that the output you see is not an error at all, it is simply the string representation of the tensor you have created.